# Difference of two pictures as a percentage

Tags: matlab

I want to compare edges of two 'jpg' images. I used 'imshowpair' function to do that. But I need to get the difference as a percentage value. How can I do it? Please help....

```
img1 = imread('3.jpg');
img2 = imread('4.jpg');

gr1 = rgb2gray(img1);
gr2 = rgb2gray(img2);

ed1 = edge(gr1,'canny');
ed2 = edge(gr2,'canny');

comp1 = imshowpair(ed1,ed2,'diff');
```

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried with actual code snippets.

Comment: I have added the code I used..

Comment: I don't understand your question.  `imshowpair` with the `diff` option simply subtracts the two images together and places an absolute sign.  I don't understand how you can get this as a percentage.  Can you please clarify what you mean by percentage?  Do you want to compare how many dissimilar pixels there are in the same spatial locations between the images?

Comment: Depends on how you define percentage: Percentage from what? Do you mean how many pixels are different proportional to the total number of pixels in the image?

Comment: Any comment on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Any two images `I` and `J` of same size can be compared in a variety of ways; there are plenty of similarity and dissimilarity measures that can be used (cosine metric, cross-correlation, gradient cross-correlation, mutual information, etc.).

In your case, the way I understand your question is "what is the ratio of pixels that are different in both images". To that question the answer is:

```
d = sum( abs(I(:)-J(:)) > eps ) / numel(I);
```

but understand that this is a rather weak comparison metric. 
For instance, it doesn't tell you *how different* the images are in places where they are not equal.

This can be improved (e.g. by computing the average difference), and can be extended to the case where `I` and `J` do not have the same size (e.g. by first resizing them, or comparing pairs of equal-size random patches instead).